# Flutter right overflow two texts in row

Tags: flutter, dart, text, row, overflow

I want to put 2 Text in one Row. I do the following:

```dart
Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, children: [
  Flexible(
      child: Text(text1,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
  Flexible(
      child: Text(text2,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
]),
```

Here I have shown the result expected with overflows and actual:

[image]

None of the Text can expand more than half the total length of the Row, even if there is free space. How to implement the result I expect, despite the fact that the length of Text1 and Text2 may be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the length of the strings to split the area available to each one using calculated `flex` values in `Flexible`. The result will not always be optimal with non monospaced fonts, but somehow you have to assign how many space should the texts occupy. You could use `Expanded` to fill the remaining available space, but it only works if you have a fixed width item and use `Expanded` on the other one.

Try this (setting width on the `Container` and red color is only for demonstration):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final text1 = 'Text111111111111111111';
    final text2 = 'Text222';

    return Container(
        width: 200,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          Flexible(
              flex: text1.length,
              child: Text(text1,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
          Flexible(
              flex: text2.length,
              child: Text(text2,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

add MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween for row it will put space between the text aligning them to left and right.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was little bit different. In my my case the first text is label which generally requires minimum length 30 and maximum length 50 in percentage. So created a method which calculates flex factor according to texts length. You can change this threshold as per you requirement.

```
Pair<int, int> getTextRowFlexFactor(String? text1, String? text2) {
  /**
   * if flex == 0 -> the child is inflexible and determines its own size
   * if flex == 1 -> the amount of space the child's can occupy in the main axis is determined by dividing
   * the free space (after placing the inflexible children) according to the flex factors of the flexible children.
   */
  if (isNullOrEmpty(text1) && isNullOrEmpty(text2)) {
    return const Pair(0, 0);
  } else if (isNullOrEmpty(text1)) {
    return const Pair(0, 1);
  } else if (isNullOrEmpty(text2)) {
    return const Pair(1, 0);
  }

  const minText1LengthPercent = 30;
  const maxText1LengthPercent = 50;

  final text1Length = text1!.length;
  final text2Length = text2!.length;

  final text1LengthPercent = ((text1Length / text2Length) * 100).toInt();

  // when text1LengthPercent < minText1LengthPercent,
  // make text1 widget inflexible and other one flexible
  if (text1LengthPercent < minText1LengthPercent) {
    return const Pair(0, 1);
  } 
  // when text1LengthPercent > maxText1LengthPercent,
  // make text1 widget flexible and other one inflexible
  else if (text1LengthPercent > maxText1LengthPercent) {
    return const Pair(1, 0);
  }
  return const Pair(1, 1);
}

final textRowFlexFactor = getTextRowFlexFactor(text1, text2);

return  Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Flexible(
        flex: textRowFlexFactor.left, 
        child:Text(
          text1,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        )),
    Flexible(
        flex: textRowFlexFactor.right,
        child: Text(
          text2,
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        )),
  ],
);
```

To know more about the flex property -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html